# Best of 2 IELTS Scores?

Tags: canada, ielts

Just curious about the question: if one had two genral IELTS Scores which are still valid:

first general IELTS: L8 S8 R6 W6

second general IELTS: L6 S6 R7.5 W7

like best will be: L8 S8 R7.5 W7?

can they consider best of two or three if one had 3 tests? if yes, is that written anywhere on CIC website?

This question is related to Express Entry and QSW.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: No. Only one test is considered.

Answer (score 3):

Only one Test Result Form, the one which you submit and is valid at that time will be considered. No matter if it is old, new, better, worse, only requirement is it should be valid at the time of application.

```
*Test Result Form = TRF = IELTS Score Card.
```

Edit: Most of the time TRFs are valid for two years from the exam date.